Safari 17.5 misreporting screen.width
iMac 27" (2015) Monterey 12.7.5 Safari Version 17.5 (17618.2.12.111.5, 17618)
I have been playing around with dynamic resizing and suddenly (since early May) the values reported by Safari for screen.width & screen.height are not the dimensions of the whole screen (2560 x 1440) - but instead are the same as screen.availWidth & screen.availHeight (1300 x 800)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The Window Screen Object</h1>
<h2>The width Property</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
let width = screen.width;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =  width + "px";
</script>

</body>
</html>


Tested in Safari on iMac (fails), latest Firefox and Chrome (same iMac) passes. Works perfectly in w3school's 'try it now'.
I have reported this to Apple, but I was wondering if anyone else has noticed / tested / resolved this?

You likely have  “enhanced protection against tracking and fingerprinting” -> under Privacy -> Advanced.  option selected in your browser,   screen.width is one of those fingerprinting properties.

That's the solution alright! Thank you, and I hope someone else finds this useful. However, that setting is in place on my MacBook and Pro and the problem does not exist there (both laptops are Ventura 13.6.7 Safari 17.5).

I believe there is a setting to enable just for private browsing, your macBook and Pro might only be set for private browsing.

Yes, that appears to be exactly how these laptops are configured. Another mystery solved.
